# angular typeahead rendering issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to use `angular typeahead`.
Its loading my complete `data` but not showing the line items.

This is my code.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item as item.entityName for item in testsList |filter:$viewValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Start typing to search tests and select it">
```

My ui.bootstrap version is `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0`

Hope somebody will come up with relevant answer.

I have attached the concerned screenshot of the out.[image]

Comment: Does your items objects have the `entityName` property?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `testsList`?  And ui-bootstrap recently got new labeling, and they prefix everything with `uib` now (I'm not sure what your version of ui-bootstrap uses).

Comment: [{"id": 50472,"erTypeId": 9716, "erTypeName": "Annual Health Check", "serviceBrokerId": 1000042,"serviceBrokerName": "ABCD", "entityId": 1006789,"entityName": "Yokogawa India Limited","startDate": "/Date(1438194600000-0000)/", "endDate": "/Date(1469817000000-0000)/","documentType": 0,"isActive": true,"entityTypeId": 0,"stateId": 64,"districtId": 574,"cityId": 2791,"locationId": 0,"pinCode": "560040","attachDocIds": [],"isBreakfast": false,"isMammogram": false,"isSoftcopy": false}]

Comment: i mentioned the object above which contains entityName as Yokogawa India Limited